# SQL Server 2010 Grouping increments

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am having a problem getting my head around how to group data based upon when a zero appears in a column to start a new group.  Whilst there are numerous solutions I've not managed to get any of them to fit.

One of the problems is currently my largest set has 178 zeros and so repeat iterations from joins or unions seems to be out of the question.

Here is a small sample of the data.  All we need for this is the Low_Link.  Each time the Low_Link is zero a new incremented rank value is to be added.  I have included a rank column in the data to show what it should be.

Any help appreciated!

```
+----------+----------+-----------+------+
| Order_ID | Low_Link | High_Link | Rank |
+----------+----------+-----------+------+
|        1 |        0 |         2 |    1 |
|        2 |        1 |         3 |    1 |
|        3 |        2 |         4 |    1 |
|        4 |        0 |         5 |    2 |
|        5 |        4 |         6 |    2 |
|        6 |        5 |         7 |    2 |
|        7 |        6 |         8 |    2 |
|        8 |        0 |         9 |    3 |
|        9 |        8 |        10 |    3 |
|       10 |        9 |        11 |    3 |
|       11 |       10 |        12 |    3 |
|       12 |       11 |        13 |    3 |
|       13 |       12 |        14 |    3 |
|       14 |        0 |        15 |    4 |
|       15 |       14 |        16 |    4 |
|       16 |       15 |        17 |    4 |
|       17 |        0 |        18 |    5 |
|       18 |        0 |        19 |    6 |
|       19 |        0 |        20 |    7 |
|       20 |       19 |        21 |    7 |
|       21 |        0 |        22 |    8 |
|       22 |        0 |        99 |    9 |
|       23 |        0 |        99 |   10 |
|       24 |        0 |        99 |   11 |
|       25 |        0 |        99 |   12 |
+----------+----------+-----------+------+
```

Comment: There is **no** SQL Server **2010** version - we have 2000, 2005, 2008, 2008 R2, 2012, 2014, 2016 and 2017 - take your pick .....

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server 2008, you can assign the rank by counting the number of 0s that occur *before* each value:

```
select t.*,
       (select count(*)
        from t t2
        where t2.order_id <= t.order_id and t2.low_link = 0
       ) as rank 
from t;
```

This will not be particularly efficient.  In SQL Server 2012+ you can use the `order by` in window functions which would significantly speed up this query.

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when low_link = 0 then 1 else 0 end) over
           (order by order_id) as rnk
from t;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon.  One slight modification for <= got it working exactly as I need.  Much appreciated :)  Oh and sadly we can't update this server at the moment so have to keep it on 2010 :(  Would be a lot easier in 2012 plus.

Answer (score 0):

One more option with `cross apply`.

```
select t.*,tt.rnk
from tbl t
cross apply (select sum(case when t1.low_link=0 then 1 else 0 end) as rnk
             from tbl t1
             where t1.id<=t.id 
            ) tt
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Window` function, easily achieve this:

```
DECLARE @Tab TABLE(id INT, low_Rank INT)
INSERT INTO @Tab VALUES (1,0)
INSERT INTO @Tab VALUES (2,1)
INSERT INTO @Tab VALUES (3,2)
INSERT INTO @Tab VALUES (4,0)
INSERT INTO @Tab VALUES (5,1)
INSERT INTO @Tab VALUES (6,2)
INSERT INTO @Tab VALUES (7,3)
INSERT INTO @Tab VALUES (8,0)
INSERT INTO @Tab VALUES (9,1)

SELECT *
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN low_Rank=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(ORDER BY id) [Rank]
FROM @Tab
```

**Output:**

```
id  low_Rank    Rank
1   0           1
2   1           1
3   2           1
4   0           2
5   1           2
6   2           2
7   3           2
8   0           3
9   1           3
```